# Bad input error in Python 2.7 in multiple inputs

Tags: python, input, types

I am taking an intro course in Python and the assignment is to figure the area I have the inputs working, but I'm getting an error on the first `elif` (triangle).  It has something to do with the data type, but I'm new to Python and would appreciate a hand...

```
def get_shape(input):
  #print("You entered %s inside the function.") % (input)
  return input.upper()
allowed_shapes = ["C", "T", "R"]
print
print("Let's calculate the area of a shape!")
print
print("Enter \"C\" for a circle, \"T\" for a triangle, or \"R\" for a rectangle...")
print
shape = get_shape(input = raw_input("Enter a shape:"))

while shape not in allowed_shapes:
  print("You must enter either a (C)ircle, (T)riangle or (R)ectangle.")
  print
  shape = get_shape(input = raw_input("Enter a shape:"))

if shape == "C":
  print("You chose C.")
  radius = float(raw_input("Enter the radius of the circle...:"))
  print
  print "The area of your circle is %f square units." % ((radius**2) * 3.14159)
elif shape == "T":
  print("You chose T.")
  t_base = float(raw_input("Enter the base of the triangle...:"))
  t_height = float(raw_input("Enter the height of the triangle...:"))
  print
  print "The area of your triangle is %f square units." % ((t_base * t_height) / 2))
else:
  print("You chose R.")
  legnth = float(raw_input("Enter the legnth of the rectangle...:"))
  width = float(raw_input("Enter the width of the rectangle...:"))
  print
  print "The area of your rectangle is %f square units." % (legnth * width)
```

Comment: Please provide your full python code to figure the error.

Comment: Edited to add full code...

Comment: It would help if include (cut and paste)  the full exact error that you received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got an extra round bracket here

```
print "The area of your triangle is %f square units." % ((t_base * t_height) / 2))
```

It should look like this

```
print "The area of your triangle is %f square units." % ((t_base * t_height) / 2)
```